# Loop works fine in jQuery but won't work in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, salesforce

I'm trying to create an array from a complicated JSON response.  I have working jQuery code that I'm trying to adapt to Angular but it won't work.

Here is the jQuery code that works just fine:

```
j$.each(data.groupingsDown.groupings, function(di, de) {
var values = [];
reportData.push({"key":de.label, "values": values});
    j$.each(data.groupingsAcross.groupings, function(ai, ae) {
        values.push({"x": ae.label, "y": data.factMap[de.key+"!"+ae.key].aggregates[0].value});
    });
});
```

Here is version I'm trying to use in Angular that will not work:

```
angular.forEach(data.groupingsDown.groupings, function (di, de) {
var values = [];
reportData.push({'key' : de.label, 'values' : values});
    angular.forEach(data.groupingsAcross.groupings, function (ai, ae) {
        values.push({'x' : ae.label, 'y' : data.factMap[de.key + '!' + ae.key].aggregates[0].value});
    });
});
```

The error message I'm receiving is:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'aggregates' of undefined

The offending line appears to be

```
[de.key + '!' + ae.key]
```

How can I make this work in Angular just like it does in jQuery?

Comment: angular forEach works passes function(value, key) unlike jquery function(key, value) ... may be this is the reason

Comment: Yes - that was it!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per gaurav5430's comment, I needed to reverse (key, value) and make it (value, key).

So changing the 2 functions

```
function(di, de)
function(ai, ae)
```

to

```
function(de, di)
function(ae, ai)
```

solved the problem.